# Is there a way to hide a vertically overflowing table?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbyzER

```
<div> <!-- Div has set height, overflow hidden-->
   <table>
   <!-- Tons of rows --> 
  </table>
</div>
```

Ignore the mess of inline CSS. The table seems to overflow its wrapping div no matter what I do.

Comment: It seems to work as expected? If you want the overflow to be hidden with no scrollbar you need to change `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: @Cfreak Doesnt seem to be working? Inspect the table with dev console http://i.imgur.com/tW16LVf.png

Comment: I changed it in your example myself and it worked fine. If you're running it in some other code then something else is wrong.

Comment: @Cfreak Did you see the attached image in my previous comment? Even with your suggestion in the codepen the table still overflows

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Instead of, or in addition to, `overflow-x: hidden`, you should use `overflow-y: hidden`.

If it is not working for you, you are doing something else wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                border:solid 1px red;
                height:128px;
                overflow-y:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
                <tr><td>X</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working? Inspect the table element using dev console http://i.imgur.com/tW16LVf.png